# WaitForDebugEvent() API on .NET application

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, windbg

I have a launcher application that creates a process and monitors it with the WaitForDebugEvent/ContinueDebugEvent API functions. That application is written i C++ and it works fine for the unmanaged applications.

I also have a .NET application that crashes randomly. I wanted to use the laucher application to catch the exception, write the minidump and examine it with the WinDbg. But, unfortunately the WaitForDebugEvent/ContinueDebugEvent combination doesn't work for .NET applications. When the exception happens, the .NET application is silently closed and the launcher application reports no exceptions at all, like everything is fine.
Even if some exception has occurred in this situation, it's been mysteriously handled by something unknown to me.

Is there any special way of handling the .NET? Some special API calls for catching "special" .NET exceptions, etc... Google didn't help at all.

Comment: Try running your application under adplus or windbg, see if you catch something.

Comment: That's possible and WinDbg will catch it, but runing it through the WinDbg is extremly slow. I cannot use it ou user side. I need some launcher that will not slow down the application. The problem is, I have one such exception that only one user is experiencing and I'm not able to reproduce it. That user should run the application throgh the launcher.

Comment: adplus.vbs was made just for such cases. Give it a try — http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350

Comment: So, WinDbg and all other debuggers are using adplus.vbs for catching this exception/problem?

Comment: No, they use a common library — dbghelp.dll I believe.

Comment: ProcDump is another option. It can do what your C++ app does.

Comment: Have you considered using Windows Error Reporting? <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx> I know this doesn't answer your specific question but, if you're on Windows 2008+, WER would enable you to catch process crashes across the system.

Answer (score 0):

You  may add an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException in .Net and catch all exceptions arising from .Net.